# Gridview template Javascript databinding

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview. I want to bind something like:

```
<asp:TemplateField //stuff>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblEx" runat="server" text='<%# SomeJavascriptFunction( Eval("BOUND_FIELD_FROM_DB") ) %>' ></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This exact syntax doesn't appear to be working - it's telling me the function isn't declared (it is). I'm thinking it's looking for SomeJavascriptFunction() in the code-behind. Is there some way to make this work?

I can't seem to find the correct verbiage in my searches - results all seem to be regarding binding a gridview through javascript, which is not exactly correct.

**EDIT:**

I do have a code-behind version implemented and working - I'd just like to take the processing load off the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so try with some jQuery magic:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id*=lblEx]").each(function () {
            $(this).text(someJavascriptFunction($(this).text()));
        });
    });
    function someJavascriptFunction(id) {
        return "the final text in the cell";
    }
```

i've tested this and works.

Greetings,

Comment: Unfortunately not. This just renders SomeJavascriptFunction(<%# Eval("BOUND_FIELD_FROM_DB")%>) to the cell.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not at all familiar with JQuery, but this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is looking for a code behind method `SomeJavascriptFunction()` and the data returned from it will bind to the Label. You can add the corresponding method in code behind:

```
public string SomeJavascriptFunction(object obj)
{
    return "Some value";
}
```